# Optimizing image files on Lravel Vapor

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I'm using Laravel Vapor to host a site. Up until now, I've not had a problem with the lack of a filesystem, but now I've hit a brick wall.

I'm trying to optimize .png and .jpeg files, and the libraries I found require a filesystem to write the compressed files:

1. Image Optimizer (https://github.com/spatie/image-optimizer)
2. PHP Image Cache (https://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/)

I'm guessing that I can set up an external service that runs on an additional traditional server... But I'd prefer to make it work with Vapor.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of optimizing do you need? There is 500mb of local storage so you could use it but if you are just resizing/creating thumbnails you do not need local storage. You can read/write directly from/to S3.

Comment: @BobB , I hardly need any storage space at all, just for optimizing image files one at a time. The problem is that the functions in both libraries take the location of the optimized output file as an argument, and you can't do that with S3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GD Library or Imagick directly?
Using Imagick with files on s3 you can do something like this:

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$file = $s3->get('tmp/'.$uuid); // assuming Vapor upload to S3 here
$imagick = new \Imagick(); // extension can be added to Vapor.
$imagick->readImageBlob($file);
$imagick->thumbnailImage(200,200);// whatever size you are looking for.
$s3->put('path/on/s3/for/your/optimized/file',$imagick->getImageBlob(),['CacheControl' => 'max-age=10000000, public', 'ACL' => 'public-read']) // whatever options you need
```

Note both read and write are from/to s3 directly. No need to write to local disk